# User.Identity.Name returns null after being mocked

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, moq

I am having a bit of a rough time trying to figure out why my mocked User.Identity.Name is returning null when I run my test. I have a feeling that I may have screwed up when I called my controller.ControllerContext because I am setting up some routes at that point, but I am unsure how to adjust to go back to assigning an object as I have done on previous tests. I'm using Moq with MSTest. Here is my test:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Leave_Request_Process_Approved()
    {
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "myAPI", routeTemplate: "api/myFolder/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);

        var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        session.SetupGet(s => s["altUser"]).Returns("Mod");
        controllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        controllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns("User");
        controllerContext.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress).Returns("127.0.0.1");

        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        request.Setup(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
        request.Setup(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://temp-removed"));
        request.Setup(x => x.ServerVariables).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection());

        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);

        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        response.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(x => x);
        context.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

        var controller = new myController();
        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), controller);
        controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData()), routes);

        Assert.IsNotNull(controller.Process(5058, "A", ""));

    }
```

With tests I have built in the past, I normally have for my controller.ControllerContext:

```
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
```

I have tried to see if there is any controllerContext.Setup options or context.Setup options I could use, but Intellisense doesn't provide me with any options that I can see to be able to replace where I call in my route information.

Comment: Think maybe you hurt its feelings?

Comment: Now, I don't know Moq at all, nor MVC (which I think this is), so just a shot in the dark here. Where does your mocked controller context come into play here? I see you set it up early in the method, but I don't see it used.

Comment: "In Soviet Russia, User.Identity.Name mocks you"   (sorry, couldn't resist)

Comment: That's where I am a bit lost. I already make an assignment to controller.ControllerContext for my routes. I can't make another assignment as I have in other tests because that overwrites my original assignment. I don't know how to call my mocked controller context without losing my mocked routes.

Comment: Ah. Didn't pay enough attention to the text of the question. I hope you get an answer from folks with domain knowledge here. You might consider applying additional tags, if any might be applicable, so as to draw their attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mocking the `ControllerContext`, you should be able to just set up a mock for the `HttpContextBase.User`:

```
context.SetupGet(c => c.User.Identity.Name).Returns("user");
```

And then pass that mocked Http context to the `ControllerContext` ctor.

Comment: That worked beautifully. I've accepted the answer, as it answered my original post, but I have a related question for you. When I try to do a similar thing to mock the UserHostAddress (I've tried in both context and request), the IP address displays as null. I'm not receiving any exceptions on it, but I happened to notice it is null when I was examining a different error.

Comment: Set the mock up for UserHostAddress on your request mock, not on Context.Request.UserHostAddress (which gets ignored later on when you override Context.Request to return your request mock).